# Identify a large wasp (?) from southern Poland

Tags: species-identification, entomology, wasps, bees

This insect has appeared "out of nowhere" in one of my rooms. Can you help me identify it?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Details:

- location: [**Katowice, Upper Silesia, southern Poland, eastern Europe**](https://goo.gl/maps/nEhqACMc3XbtmQH58) (46.42 N, 17.78 E),
- date: **April 3rd, 2021** (early Spring, approx. 3:10 pm).

At first I was more than sure that this is large male bee / wasp / Apidae family member. But I was surprised to see absolutely no signs of yellow or orange strips, only gray ones, if I am not mistaken.

The windows were closed tightly at the moment of its appearance and were not open too many times in the days before, as we still have kind of cold early Spring here, in Poland right now. Though I must admit that we had a very warm previous weekend (March 27th/28th) with temperatures of up to 19°C / 66°F. But, I am still unsure, if it appeared just "these days", or if it was able (in some *magical way*) to survive somewhere behind wardrobe since past Autumn (very not likely?).

It was very weak at the moment of finding it. It was certainly unable to fly though its wings seemed OK. It was looking like it had at least one leg broken. He was moving very slowly and attaching itself to any surface it found (piece of paper, ruler etc.). I moved it gently to my balcony / piece of grass and let the nature do the rest.

Comment: it is not a wasp it is a bumblebee,i did see this years first bumblebee a coupe of hours ago here in norway,they do wake up now in the start of spring to start a new hive.i do not know what type you have there but it shoul be fairly easy for you to find a listing for your country.

Comment: the bumblebee might be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombus_ruderarius or it might be bombus subterraneous but this last one is rare to find in the north of europe.